# How to play media file in Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, media-player

I am using Cordova and the media plugin.
My own files play pretty well, but not when trying to play a ringtone with such an uri:

```
content://media/internal/audio/media/107
```

How can I play such a file using the media plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, for usage without JAVA:

```
content://media/internal/audio/media/107
Title: Luna
```

goes to

```
file:///system/media/internal/audio/media/107/luna.ogg
```

Be aware that you would usually read the real path from the DB of the path.